# Data Transfer Objects return values

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, data-transfer-objects

Should Data Transfer Objects always be used to transfer data? Please see the code below:

```
public function getPerson(ByVal id As integer) As Person
    return Person
end function

public function getPersonAge(ByVal id As integer) As Integer
    return age
end function
```

The first function returns every piece of information for the person and can probably be reused again and again, when getting information e.g. address about the person in other parts of the application.  getPersonAge is slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more clear. But if your question is solely "Should DTOs only be used to transfer data" the answer is yes.

A good use of DTOs is keeping in mind that they are only a bunch of getters/setters/properties like: `public int MyProperty { get; set; }`.

In MVC you can see them as ViewModels but then not for views, but for the several layers in your application.